# Continuously Scan Directory and Perform Script on New Items

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ffmpeg, monitor

First, please forgive me and be easy on me if this question seems easy; the first time I tried posting a question about another subject, I didn't provide enough information a few months ago. My apologies.

I'm trying to scan my incoming media folder for new audio files and convert them to my preferred format into another folder, without removing the originals.

I've written the script below and while it seems to work for one-offs, I can't seem to get it to create the destination directory name based off the source directory name; and I can't seem to figure out how to keep it looping, "scanning", for new media to arrive without processing what it's already processed.

I hope this makes sense...

```
#! /bin/bash

srcExt=$1
destExt=$2

srcDir=$3
destDir=$4

opts=$5

# Creating the directory name - not currently working
#   dirName="$(basename "$srcDir")"
#   mkdir "$destDir"/"$dirName"

for filename in "$srcDir"/*.flac; do

    basePath=${filename%.*}
    baseName=${basePath##*/}
    
    ffmpeg -i "$filename" $opts "$destDir"/"$baseName"."$destExt"

done

for filename in "$srcDir"/*.mp3; do

    basePath=${filename%.*} 
    baseName=${basePath##*/}

    ffmpeg -i "$filename" $opts "$destDir"/"$baseName"."$destExt"

done
```

Answer (score 0):

there are different ways of doing this, the easiest way might just be to look at the "modification date" of the file and seeing if it has changed, something like:

```
#! /bin/bash

srcExt=$1
destExt=$2

srcDir=$3
destDir=$4

opts=$5

# Creating the directory name - not currently working
#   dirName="$(basename "$srcDir")"
#   mkdir "$destDir"/"$dirName"

for filename in ` find "$srcDir" \( -name '*.mp3' -o -name '*.flac' \)  -mmin -10`; do

    basePath=${filename%.*}
    baseName=${basePath##*/}
    
    ffmpeg -i "$filename" $opts "$destDir"/"$baseName"."$destExt"

done
```

Comment: This truly shows my level of understanding in bash so far, it never occurred to me to search for a timestamp. I was thinking I was going to have to create some sort of index, but really the index exists in the timestamp itself. Something like this should work perfectly. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I'm sorry - I tried this example, and played around with it and I simply can't get it to work: Even removing the `-mmin +120` resulted in nothing happening. I've changed the -regex to `'.*\(mp3\|flac\)$'` and this seemed to at least get the script to begin searching the directory but - it is not able to locate the files because it is erroring out on spaces in the file names.

Thoughts?

Comment: sorry, was doing it from memory.  I've tested the code, and edited my answer above

Comment: Thanks for the help - this solution still seems to work the best, however, I am still unable to get the script to work: Each "space" in the file-name or directory structure it is returning is being treated as a separate file; which, of course, is causing an error.

Comment: have you tried adding double-quotes on the definitions of basePath and baseName ? `basePath="${filename%.*}"` and `baseName="${basePath##*/}"`

Comment: No such luck -- I'm still digging around for solutions, if you find one please let me know. You've been a great help.

Comment: I'm getting closer, using `SAVEIFS=$IFS` and `IFS=$'\n'` before the find statement, but I changed the line that previously started with `for...` to `find "$srcDir"/ -type f \( -name '*.mp3' -o -name '*.flac' \) -print | while read i ;do mkdir -p "$destDir"/`dirname "${i:1}"`

Now I've just got some cleanup - and fixing of paths.

Answer (score 0):

- Consider using `mkdir -p` which will a) create all necessary intermediate directories, and b) not complain if they already exist.
- If you want the new items to be processesd *immediately* they arrive, look at `inotify` or `fswatch` on **macOS**. In general, if less urgent, schedule your job to run every 10 minutes under `cron`, maybe prefixing with `nice` so as not to be a CPU *"hog"*.
- Decide which files to generate by changing directory to the source directory and iterating over all files. For each file, work out what the corresponding output file should be according to your rules, test if it already exists, if not create it.

Don't repeat all your `for` loop code like that, just do:

```
cd "$srcDir"
for filename in *.flac *.mp3 ; do
    GENERATE OUTPUT FILENAME
    if [ ! -f "$outputfilename" ] ; then
        mkdir -p SOMETHING
        ffmpeg -i "$filename" ... "$outputfilename"
    fi
done
```